# Write a CSV from Dictionary with Values as Header Keys Aligned Under

Tags: python

Trying to write a csv from a dictionary where the csv header are the dictionary values and the keys are aligned under matching values.

```
alternate_names = { 'advertisement' : 'advertising',
                    'ads' : 'advertising',
                    "adverts" : "advertising",
                    'distributor' : 'distribution'}
```

Would then become as csv as:

> advertising, distribution
> advertisement, distributor
> ads
> adverts

Seems quite simple if the keys are the header rather than the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import csv
import collections
import itertools

alternate_names = { 'advertisement' : 'advertising',
                    'ads' : 'advertising',
                    "adverts" : "advertising",
                    'distributor' : 'distribution'}

groups = collections.defaultdict(list)
for word, group in alternate_names.items():
    groups[group].append(word)

with open('results.csv', 'w') as fh:
    writer = csv.writer(fh)
    writer.writerow(groups.keys())
    for row in itertools.zip_longest(*groups.values()):
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Probably the key trick is that `zip` or `zip_longest` can be used to transpose a matrix in 'list of lists' form.

Comment: Oddly getting an additional blank row between each entry but it's 99% of the way there. Brilliant.

Comment: Hmm, should that file be open in `'wt'` mode instead? Otherwise, you may be getting a newline as part of your input data, or otherwise writing an extra newline somewhere...

Comment: I specified no newline character with the open call ```with open('results.csv', 'wt', newline='') as fh:``` and that seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

A variant...

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

alternate_names = { 'advertisement' : 'advertising',
                    'ads' : 'advertising',
                    "adverts" : "advertising",
                    'distributor' : 'distribution'}

ig1 = itemgetter(1)

groups = {k:[x[0] for x in v] for k,v in
          groupby(sorted(alternate_names.items(), key=ig1), ig1)}

data = groups.values()

with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(groups.keys())
    for i in range(max(len(v) for v in data)):
        writer.writerow(col[i] if i < len(col) else '' for col in data)
```